# Azure ADF @replace expression how to escape the \ character

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Azure ADF expressions can't parse this for some reason.

This is the expression used to set variable activity of a string variable named "out".
`@replace('whats\up','\','/')`

The error is:
`Invalid Position 25 Syntax error: Missing comma between arguments` which actually points to the `/` character

@'\' &/ @'/' doesn't make a difference.
Neither does any combination of '\\', '/', ....

Actually my value `what\up` is assigned a variable named 'in'.
So the real expression is: `@replace(variables('in'),'\','/')`
It yields the same error but a `Position 30`

There isn't anything I can find that comes close to explaining the expression engine/compilation/execution in ADF.

Sorry for the crappy screen camera shots.  But the bubbles don't screen capture
[image]
[image]

Comment: I tested set variable activity based on your description,but no error occurred. Please give more details about your configuration,such as code of activity or screenshot,please.

Comment: I have a pipeline.  Reduced to a single 'Set Variable' activity the string variable name is 'out'.  The dynamic content expression is `@replace('whats\up, '\', '/')`
The error is `...Position 25...`
What do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enter image description here@replace('whats\up, '\', '/') You missed a single quote ' after up.

```
{
"name": "pipeline14",[![enter image description here][1]][1]
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Set Variable1",
            "type": "SetVariable",
            "typeProperties": {
                "variableName": "a",
                "value": "@replace('whats\\up','\\','/')"
            }
        }
    ],
    "variables": {
        "a": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    }
}
```

}
[image]

[image]

Comment: The only place I missed that closing single-quote was in the response I typed to Jay Gong. Read the OP.

Comment: I tried your expression, it works well.  Just simply use. @replace('whats\up','\','/')

Comment: Do you mind building a super simple example pipeline and posting the entire code?

Comment: Posted. Just try debug it. And i noticed that if you enter it in UI, you don't need escape. But if you use json code, then, you need escape.

Comment: Thank you for doing that.  I have two image I'll try to post on this OP to show you what I see.  Check them out.

Comment: You don't see these validation errors in your portal's pages?

Do you know what region your subscription is in?

Comment: Oh, I think I just pasted  the string into that input box, instead of using add dynamic content. I will try dynamic content later. But to unblock you, you could just use my method.

Comment: Hi Steve. I saw the error message. But if you try debug it, you will find the pipeline run successfully. So that should be an expression validation bug. I will contact PROD team.

Comment: I see what you are saying.  It is an error in both the web UI & the UI's validation.